# Тег <video> в Internet Explorer 10

Tags: html, internet-explorer, iis

Не открывается сайт с тегом `<video>` в Internet Explorer 10 и 11 ниже код подскажите как можно исправить эту проблему в хроме всё нормально. Сайт развёрнут на сервере IIS 7

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Video Demo</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <video width="400"
               height="300"
               src="video/V1.mp4"

               autoplay
               controls
               loop>
            This content appears if the video tag or the codec is not supported.
        </video>
    </body>

    </html>
```

В общем после дня головоломки проблему из за чего не открывается нашёл в консоли пишет (не сразу заметил) "Подключенная страница рассчитана на режим документов 5. Некоторые API и возможности консоли могут быть недоступны". Но если в Эмуляции Режим документов изменить его руками с 5 на По фронту то всё работает. Как его заставить быть всегда по фронту ps. если сайт окатывать через Localhost то всё нормально

Comment: Смотрите логи сервера. Если там ни чего нет, открывайте средства разработчика в IE  Там - сеть и консоль ошибок глядите.

Comment: @Visman ошибок нету. Ругался на активное содержимое включил   Разрешать запуск активного содержимого файлов на моем компьютере. Но проблема осталась. У меня та страница открывается во Frame если страницу открыть на прямую то всё нормально

Comment: так может стоит посмотреть в сторону настроек безопасности IE?

Comment: @Visman проверил все настройки всё нормально.

Answer (score 2):

Всё проблему решил. Оказалось что нужно было прописать `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />` не на страницы с видео а на странице с `Frameset`