# Проблема отображения страницы в Internet Explorer 11

Tags: java, html, gwt

Добрый день.

Есть Web-приложение которое запускается через IE11.

Проблема в том, что если это приложение размещено на локальном веб-сервере. Оно запускается и отображается нормально. Если это приложение перенести на удаленный сервер (где также IE11), то там (локально) оно запускается нормально, а с удаленного компьютера через IE11 начинает "чудить" с отображением HTML-страницы.

тот же google chrome отрабатывает нормально (что удалённо что локально), но в конторе IE11 это корп. стандарт.

Подскажите, в какую сторону глядеть?

Comment: а какие ошибки в консоли?

Comment: "Подключенная страница рассчитана на режим документов 5. Некоторые API и возможности консоли могут быть недоступны." - вот такое сообщение.

Comment: [ссылка](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/454075/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D0%B3-video-%D0%B2-internet-explorer-10) не поможет?

Comment: О! Благодарю. Заработало! :) Ещё данный эффект достигается снятием галочки "Отображать сайты интрасети в режиме совместимости"

Comment: @Den, оформите как ответ для тех, кто в дальнейшем посетит вопрос, но только постарайтесь ссылку указать как источник, а в ответ занести именно полноценное решение вопроса.

Answer (score 2):

Решение найдено.

Благодаря [ссылке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/454075/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D0%B3-video-%D0%B2-internet-explorer-10) от Den, я добавил в загрузочную html-страницу следующий тег:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

Теперь браузер отображает страницу корректно как локально так и удаленно.

Answer (score 0):

См. [Устранение проблем с отображением сайта при просмотре в режиме совместимости в Internet Explorer 11](https://support.microsoft.com/ru-ru/help/17472/windows-internet-explorer-11-fix-site-display-problems-compatibility-v).

В моём случае помогло пойти от противного и без правки кода сделать так:

- Откройте Internet Explorer, нажмите кнопку *Сервис*  и выберите пункт *Параметры просмотра в режиме совместимости*.
- Снимите птичку *Отображать сайты интрасети в режиме совместимости*